# Is there a cross-platform library to register/handle URI schemes?

Tags: cross-platform, url-scheme, uri-scheme

Is there a library out there that allows developers to register and handle custom URI schemes on Windows, OS X, and maybe Linux?

I found [URISchemeHandler](https://github.com/beothorn/URISchemeHandler) on GitHub, which is written in Java, but it does not support OS X. I could fork it and try to implement it myself, but I don't own a Mac, so I wouldn't be able to test it properly.

Comment: Hi Rudey, did you manage to find a way around this?

Comment: @MaykonMeneghel No, I did not.